# Linked Servers and Distributed Transactions in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, distributed-transactions

I am having trouble executing a function import of a stored procedure that references a linked server.
**The Problem**

The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server ... was unable to begin a distributed transaction.

**What I have done so far**

I have been able to execute this stored procedure in SSMS and in a Classic ASP web application. It seems to only be a problem when running the stored procedure from the MVC application. I have tried running SSMS as the user specified in the Web.Config of the MVC application, and the connection strings for the classic ASP website and the MVC application are pretty much identical

**The Question**

Is there anything in particular that I need to do in order to enable Distributed Transactions in mvc3/entity framework?